# Laravel -> Carbon Date -> Set Month Week Number based on Day

Tags: laravel

I am trying to work out an issue where I need to map the "Week Number" based on a Meeting Day (ie Friday) using the Carbon Date plugin for Laravel

With the current month (March 2020), the 1st falls on a Sunday.
However I don't want Carbon to treat this as Week 1, and the following week as week 2. 
I would like the app to look at the how many Fridays in a Month and take that as how many weeks in a month.

I am using this in my Controller

```
    $date = Carbon::parse($request->get('rolldate'))->format('Y-m-d');
    $e = new Rollmapping();
    $e->roll_date = Carbon::parse($request->get('rolldate'));
    $e->roll_year = Carbon::parse($date)->year;
    $e->roll_month = Carbon::parse($date)->month;
    $e->roll_week = Carbon::parse($date)->weekNumberInMonth;
    $e->save();
```

However if I create a Roll on the 6th March I will get 2 for roll_week, were I would like 1 as this is the first Friday and continue from there, ie the following week (13th) would be week 2 and not week 3

Comment: I have checked with date `2020-03-06` and it gives `roll_week ` is `1`. so what you expect?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya I am getting 2 written into my Database

Comment: What is value of `$request->get('rolldate')`?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya, that is today's date (04-03-2020), picked this up while rewriting an update, and could foresee a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have to use `weekOfMonth` property instead of `weekNumberInMonth`

**weekNumberInMonth**

> weekNumberInMonth consider weeks from monday to sunday, so the week 1 will contain 1 day if the month start with a sunday, and up to 7 if it starts with a monday.

**weekOfMonth**

> weekOfMonth will returns 1 for the 7 first days of the month, then 2 from the 8th to the 14th, 3 from the 15th to the 21st, 4 from 22nd to 28th and 5 above

```
echo \Carbon\Carbon::parse('first friday')->weekOfMonth;
> 1

echo \Carbon\Carbon::parse('first friday')->weekNumberInMonth;
> 2
```

Also you have to consider if first day of month is between sunday to friday folowing comparasions:

```
var_dump(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('first day')->gt('first sunday') && \Carbon\Carbon::parse('first day')->lt('first friday'));
> false
```

If so you have to add 1 to `weekOfMonth` property

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, That will get me out of trouble.